# how to make my custom directive depends on ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I want to know how to make my custom directive depends on ng-model? Which line to add in `app.directive('myDirective',...` so that myDirective module will depend on ngModel?

Comment: Do people even know what google is anymore? https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/

Comment: Please provide relevant code. We don't know how your directive is configured or what you are trying to do or what you have tried

Comment: @John that's not how things work...you are expected to do basic research and show attempts before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your directive definition object, add the property

```
require: 'ngModel'
```

Comment: But it is saying **Error: No controller: ngModel** in the console

Comment: do you have an ng-model attribute on your directive?